# Wordpress get taxonomy children

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy and for each parent there are one or more children, this is an example:

[image]

I need to query this taxonomy and get the children of a defined terms.
For example I need to get all the children of `MI` and in this case should return just `Milano`.

MI have the ID set to `31` so I used this query to get all the children:

```
$children = get_term_children(31, 'posizione_geografica');
```

where `posizione_geografica` is my taxonomy slug.
If `var_dump` the `$children` I alway get `0` but, as you can see from the image, `MI` has children.

How should I modify the query?

Comment: `get_term_children()` will return an empty array if the term does not exist in WP. Are you sure `31` is the ID of `MI`? What page are you trying this on? Can you use `get_queried_object()` to return the term ID and populate the `get_term_children()` function dynamically?

Comment: Yes I'm sure about the ID. I have solved with `get_terms`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it should work fine

```
$terms = get_terms( 
        array(
            'taxonomy'   => 'posizione_geografica',
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'parent'     => 31
            ) 
    );
```

Comment: In this way it get only the parent, so `MI` not `Milano`